# C# nested HashSet comparison not working for me

Tags: c#, nested, compare, hashset, iequalitycomparer

last line return false, I would appreciate if someone could explain how come? Many thanks!

```
IEqualityComparer < HashSet<int> > hashSetComparer = HashSet<int>.CreateSetComparer();
        var h3 = new HashSet<HashSet<int>>( hashSetComparer ) { new HashSet<int>{ 1, 2 }, new HashSet<int>{ 3, 4 } };
        var h4 = new HashSet<HashSet<int>>( hashSetComparer ) { new HashSet<int>{ 4, 3 }, new HashSet<int>{ 1, 2  } };

        var h6 = new HashSet<HashSet<int>>() { new HashSet<int>{ 4, 3 }, new HashSet<int>{ 1, 2  } };

        bool b13 = h4.Contains( new HashSet<int>{ 1, 2 } ); //true
        bool b15 = h6.Contains( new HashSet<int>{ 1, 2 } ); //false

        bool b10 = h3.SetEquals( h4 ); //true

        IEqualityComparer < HashSet < HashSet<int> >>  comparer2 = HashSet<HashSet<int>>.CreateSetComparer();
        bool b14 = comparer2.Equals( h3, h4 ); //true

        //var h5 = new HashSet<HashSet<HashSet<int>>>( HashSet<HashSet<int>>.CreateSetComparer() );
        var h5 = new HashSet<HashSet<HashSet<int>>>( comparer2 );
        h5.Add( h3 );
        bool b11 = h5.Contains( h3 ); //true
        bool b12 = h5.Contains( h4 );//FALSE! WHY?
```

Comment: this is old but might answer your question - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jaredpar/2009/01/15/if-you-implement-iequatablet-you-still-must-override-objects-equals-and-gethashcode/

Comment: `HashSet<HashSet<int>>.CreateSetComparer()` that use default comparer to compare `HashSet` elements, but default comparer for `HashSet<int>` can not compare them properly.

Comment: @PetSerAl - how would you do it instead?

Comment: @Gigel You should call [this constructor](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Collections/Generic/HashSetEqualityComparer.cs,da48fa2df9750b42), but I do not see any public entry point for it.